# Running the play framework in development mode in the background

Tags: java, unix, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to find a way to run the play framework in development mode (the usual 'play run' command) but have it run in the background instead of being attached to a terminal. Unfortunately 'play run &' doesn't seem to work, the process stops instead of running and my app never works. I'm not sure why this is, just using play run and keeping the interactive terminal open works fine, but I also need to be able to run this in the background for automated deployment of development machines.

Answer (score 3):

How about `screen` as a workaround:

```
screen -S play -d -m sbt run
```

It'll terminate when sbt quits, or you can attach to it with `screen -r play`

I'm pretty sure `tmux` would work too.